nx monorepo: Unable to resolve module ../../App org/apps/test/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js
I have my project setup inside a monorepo.
The expo version is 49.0.16 and react-native 0.72.10.
The commands I execute to make the build are:
cd org
npm install
nx run test:prebuild
cd apps/test/ios
pod install

After the pods have been installed I run the build from xcode and that's when the error occurs.
The prebuild script is configured in project.json like this:
{
  "name": "test",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/test/src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "tags": [],
  "// targets": "to see all targets run: nx show project test --web",
  "targets": {
    "prebuild": {
      "executor": "@nx/expo:prebuild",
      "options": {
        "platform": "all",
        "clean": true
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "ensure-symlink",
        "sync-deps"
      ]
    }
  }
}

index.js file:
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import { App } from './src/app/App';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in Expo Go or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);

metro.config.js file:
const { withNxMetro } = require('@nx/expo');
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');
const { mergeConfig } = require('metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const { assetExts, sourceExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const customConfig = {
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== 'svg'),
    sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'cjs', 'mjs', 'svg'],
  },
};

module.exports = withNxMetro(mergeConfig(defaultConfig, customConfig), {
  // Change this to true to see debugging info.
  // Useful if you have issues resolving modules
  debug: false,
  // all the file extensions used for imports other than 'ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'
  extensions: [],
  // Specify folders to watch, in addition to Nx defaults (workspace libraries and node_modules)
  watchFolders: [],
});

